# when trying to rotate layout image goes out of screen

Tags: android, image, layout, rotation

I'm trying to rotate a layout that incluedes an image. When pressed a button layout is rotating but it goes out of screen. I have tried to rotate like this;

```
  private void changeRotation(float rotation) {
    layout.setRotation(rotation);
    layout.setTranslationX(0);
    layout.setTranslationY(0);
    layout.requestLayout();
    isRotated = true;
    newRotationValue = rotation;
}
```

My layout is like this ;

```
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/transparent"
    tools:context=".activity.CropActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top|center"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_camera"
            android:onClick="cameraBtnClick"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="Camera"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:cornerRadius="16dp"
            app:fButtonColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:shadowColor="@color/colorBlack"
            app:shadowEnabled="true"
            app:shadowHeight="2dp" />


        <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top|center"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_gallery"
            android:onClick="galleryBtnClick"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="Gallery"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:cornerRadius="16dp"
            app:fButtonColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:shadowColor="@color/colorBlack"
            app:shadowEnabled="true"
            app:shadowHeight="2dp" />

        <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top|center"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_rotate"
            android:onClick="rotateBtnClick"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="Rotate"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:cornerRadius="16dp"
            app:fButtonColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:shadowColor="@color/colorBlack"
            app:shadowEnabled="true"
            app:shadowHeight="2dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

If image is fullscreen there is no problem. but image is like this something goes wrong.

Before [image: ss]

After (press rotate button) [image: ss].

how to solve this problem ? Please help me, thanks

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: added please check it

Comment: @JDevoloper Can you post the image from before it is rotated?

Comment: posted, pls check it @VarunRaj

Comment: In your case rotation point should be center of view as `height/2` and `width/2`.

Answer (score 0):

Setting Pivot

```
layout.setPivotX(layout.getWidth() / 2);
layout.setPivotY(layout.getHeight() / 2);
```

Comment: I have already added them. Isn't "0" meaning that of beginning of screen ? what should be the value of transformpivotX and Y?

Comment: Set the translation of X to half the width of the image, and the translation of Y to half the height. Do this before you rotate.

Comment: Log what the translation for X and Y is before it rotates, then you can be sure its set correctly
"linearLayout.getTranslationX()"

Comment: after and before layout,getTranslationX and Y coming 0.0

Comment: Try with pivot instead

Comment: didnt work brother.  same result with translationX and Y method.

Answer (score 0):

For rotation of a view use as following-

To Rotate 180 degree use below

```
   layout.animate().rotation(180f).setDuration(100).start()
```

To Rotate back to normal use below

```
   layout.animate().rotation(0f).setDuration(100).start()
```

Comment: my problem is not rotation. after rotating layout it goes out of screen!

Comment: why you are using setTranslationX... setTranslationX used for translate a view from one position to another.. i think you have to remove setTranslationX and setTranslationY

Comment: please send your complete xml file

Comment: I think the problem is whether image is fullscreen or not. When I load a full screen image its working fine.When I tried to load smaller image as you see in my post, its not working. Probably this works for fullscreen images.

Comment: if you want to rotate an image than why u r rotating complete layout?

Comment: Because I'm using a custom view. I have wrote by myself this view. I need to add it to linearlayout.

Comment: I solved it resizing layout according to images. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

> when you rotate view/viewgroup it rotate with the main state
>   (land/PORTRAIT) width for ex -  you are in PORTRAIT and width is '250'
>   and height is '150' and you set view   rotation to land it do not
>   update to new width and height and due to that   you get that wrong
>   behaviour ,     to solve your problem i created simple demo

**XML**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout">
        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
                tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars[1]"
                android:id="@+id/imageView" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>
        <TextView
                android:text="Title"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp" android:layout_marginStart="16dp" android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"/>
        <Button
                android:text="Rotate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:id="@+id/button" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView" android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

**activity**

```
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.PersistableBundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import de.conlance.kotlinclean.R
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo.*
import android.content.res.Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
import android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Toast
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.stackoverflow_lo.*

class MainActivitySOF : AppCompatActivity() {

    var is90Degre = false
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.stackoverflow_lo)
        button.setOnClickListener {
            rotate()
        }
    }


    fun rotate() = if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation.equals(ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE))
    {
        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivitySOF, "Portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        setRequestedOrientation(SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
        Thread.sleep(50)




    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivitySOF, "LandScape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        setRequestedOrientation(SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
        Thread.sleep(50)



    }

    fun launchService() {
        if (SDK_INT > 25) {
            Log.v("MainActivitySOF", "25----------------------------")
            this@MainActivitySOF.startForegroundService(Intent(this@MainActivitySOF, ForGroundService::class.java))
        } else {
            startService(Intent(this, ForGroundService::class.java))
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. but you probably misunderstood my question. I dont want to rotate screen. I want to rotate layouts or views by giving degree. Landscape or portrait mode is not my answer. I have solved my problem resizing my layout according to changing images.

Answer (score 0):

add your  LinearLayout and set match_parent layout width and height

```
android:layout_gravity="center"


<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" />`
```